# Grails exiting without any error but unit of working still running on DB

Tags: sql, grails, transactional

I have a service method which is by default transactional in grails. In this method i am using SQL connection which is created by datasource to insert records into some table. Same connection i am using to update the records. I see that service is completing successfully but data is not committed and i see that at db end my updates are still going on.

For example : I tried to insert 300 records with this logic and db commit works quickly and i saw the data in db.

I tested same code for 3000 records, grails service ended error free and exception free but data is not committed at db end and i see that update on 3000 records are still going on. These updates are taking lots of time and grails job is not waiting for udpate to finish but just existing. After update is done at db side i do see data in db but how come grails is not waiting for update to finish and why after committing the transaction updates are running it should have ran before my service ended right?

```
  processrecords(){
    try{
    def sql=new Sql(dataSource)
    for(i0;i<3000;i++){
    sql.execute("Insert into A.....")
    }
    //some other work
    //some other work
    sql.executeupdate("update A set few column data") // this will again update all above 3000 inserted records.
    sql.close()
    }catch(Execption e){
       throw e
    }
    }
```

Comment: sql.executeupdate is outside the loop. Provide actual code that what you have tried, dummy / pseudo code will not help to debug your issue.

Comment: If you are using grails then you could use the GORM i.e hibernate for persisting the data.

Comment: Or a batch operation might be quicker...

Comment: try `sql.commit()`  after `sql.execute("Insert into A.....")`

Comment: sql.commit never works on sql connection opened with datasource.

Comment: @Tim yes i am updating my code to do batch inserts now.

Comment: I see the problem in my service method, after inserts and before last executeUpdate i am calling another method say M1. Inside M1 i am creating xml files and M1 is internally calling few util methods for date conversion and formatting. Once M1 creates the file call will get return to my main method "ProcessRecords" now processrecords will execute "executeUpdate" method and exit. After this exit i don't see data getting committed.

Comment: Is it something to do with transaction scoping, is it like new connections are getting creates since i am calling utils methods and grails now doesn't know which connection to commit.